# condition in Drawer at flutter

Tags: flutter, conditional-statements, navigation-drawer

I prescribe a condition that if the user is registered, then a block profile appears in the menu, but if not, then this block should not be. How can I write this correctly? He swears at the false

```
),
          isLogged == true ? ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            title: Text('Profile'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Routes.profile);
            },
          ) : false, - ???
          ListTile(
```

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code below 
For `false` condition, you can return `Container()` 
code snippet

```
isLogged == true
            ? ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                title: Text('Profile'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Routes.profile);
                },
              )
            : Container(),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isLogged = true;
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      isLogged = !isLogged;
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('Drawer Header'),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            isLogged == true
                ? ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                    title: Text('Profile'),
                    onTap: () {
                      /*Navigator.of(context).pop();
                       Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Routes.profile);*/
                    },
                  )
                : Container(),            
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Item 1'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Item 2'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it that way :

```
if(isLogged)
  ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            title: Text('Profile'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Routes.profile);
            },
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an empty Container() for the false:

```
isLogged == true ? ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
        title: Text('Profile'),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Routes.profile);
        },
      ) : Container(),
```

This displays the empty container when it's false.